# how does buf retain data in the next iteration although we are re-declaring it every time?

Tags: c, scope, block, local-variables

"Buf" should destroy after line #28, as it is local to if block and we are re-declaring then it may have some different values or at least a different memory address when re-declared.

I think, Luckily getting the same address on each declaration but can’t rely on it, isn’t it? Or a different reason?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int i=0, j=0, k=0; 

    while(3 > j) 
    { 
        if(2 > j) 
        {
            char buf[10]; 
            if (0 == j) 
            { 
                for(k=0; k<10; k++) 
                { 
                    buf[k] = 48 + k; 
                }
            } 
            puts(buf); 
        }               // line 28
        j++; 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: "then it should have some garbage value" - says *who*., and *why* ? Certainly not the standard.

Comment: What makes you think it's *not* a garbage value?  What makes you think it should have a different address?

Comment: Uninitialised variables can contain any value, and their use leads to undefined behaviour. Ryt? @WhozCraig

Comment: @JohnBollinger, the scope of local variable is the begin..end block within which it is declared. After that they will destroyed. Isn’t it? And here scope for buf is from line #19-27. 
And in next iteration, we are re-declaring it

Comment: Well, there is no `begin` or `end` in C, and "destruction" has connotations that aren't really applicable, but basically yes.  So what?

Comment: You're assuming that, because it has indeterminate initial value, and is de-scoped and re-scoped on each iteration, that the content will be "garbage". Even expecting "garbage (whatever that means) is a *determined* assumption.  I.e. "This should contain garbage.". The standard make no warrants about indeterminate content, and neither should you.

Comment: ... or to put it a different way, "garbage" in this context is a colloquialism for "indeterminate".  It describes the promises that the language spec makes (or actually, *does not* make) about the value.  It does not mean "random".  You cannot reliably recognize this kind of garbage from the value itself.  It's not like a mischievous gnome sneaks in and scrambles the bytes of each local variable at the beginning of its lifetime.

Comment: May i know why after first iteration, we are getting correct value. As buf de-scoped after first iteration.

Comment: Or is it like this, the local variable will be destroyed only when we go out of the function. And if we declare it with each iteration it doesn't affect the buffer.

Comment: Post code as text. Indent by 4 spaces.

Comment: Don't post the code in a comment. Use the "Edit" link and add the code in the question. I did it this time but now you know how to do it next time :-)

Comment: @SupportUkraine, Thank you very much :) (Actually this is my first time, and learning)

Comment: C does not have a concept of variables being "destroyed". Rather, they have a *lifetime*. Referring to a variable outside its lifetime results in UB. The `buf` variable has *automatic storage duration* and is not a variable length array so its lifetime extends from the point where its enclosing block is entered to the point where execution of its enclosing block ends in any way. For an implementation that allocates automatic storage duration objects in a stack frame, it makes sense for it to be located at the same relative position within the stack frame each time it is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i=0, j=0, k=0;
  while(3 > j) {
    if (2 > j) {
      char buf[10];     // <---- block scope in "auto" context
      if (0 == j) {
        for(k=0; k<10; k++) {
          buf[k] = 48 + k;
        }
      }     // <---- end of block for the variable char buf[]
      puts(buf);
    }
    j++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

You say

> It should destroy after line #28 *(end of block)* and as we are re-declaring then it should have some garbage value or at-least different memory address.

For the vast majority of the C compilers, a declaration without any initializer does not generate any code, it only reserves same space in memory. If that declaration is in global scope, then its memory is cleared once at the start of the program, but in a way which has little to do with "code": all global declarations are put in a special area that gets cleared at the start of runtime.

The code after the declaration (*... buf[k] = ...*) refers to a certain memory address, the one reserved for *buf[10]*. It is unlikely that, executing the block more than once, the instructions refer to different memory address - the code is compiled once... so the declaration and the subsequent code are assigned a memory address *only once*.

Given that the storage is auto, it contains garbage, as stated in previous comments. Even the results of a previous computation are to be considered "garbage". Or, if someone prefers, say "indeterminate". The compiler (and the runtime) does not initialize "auto" variables.

If you want to retain values between iterations, you declare the variable outside the block. If you don't want, you declare your variables inside the block, and ensure to fill all the data. Note that you are not doing that anyway: a string in C (buf passed to puts()) must be terminated by a NUL, but you don't put that NUL into the string.

What happens here (lack of NUL apart), is that the variable gets some memory which is only touched in that block, so it retains the previous value - but there is absolutely no warranty it would do this in other contexts (different machine, different compiler).

Put it in other words: for this sample code, there is no initialization and no destruction implicitly made. There are simply a declaration which reserves some memory, and your code which read and writes into that memory.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this nice explanation. Means local variables are destroyed when function terminates. In actuality they not destroyed, we still have data at that address just can access as we return from function. But here in that block of code where buff declared it is auto and will load to memory once and next time we are accessing the same. Please let me know if i am getting it. Also such type of implementation is not advisable, ryt? As u said it could have different behaviour on different machines

Comment: @Ankit: Yes, it's "destroyed" in a conceptual sense, in that the language no longer provides any guarantee that it is accessible.  That is not the same thing as guaranteeing that it is *not* accessible - if you see what I mean.  And "not advisable" here is an understatement.  Most people would view it as "this code is 100% buggy, and only by some stroke of amazing luck does it happen to work under these exact circumstances".

Comment: @ankit, yes you got it right. But I must stress again that variables are not *destroyed* when the function terminates. They are simply *ignored* or made hidden outside the block, ie not reachable by normal means (using pointers everything is possible...). This is the "contract" (rules) of the C language when it speaks about "out of scope" and  about undefined behavior! (I hope I am clear enough, not sure to be able to)

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica, yes, i got it thank you so much